# Is `test` a builtin or program

Tags: bash

Is test a shell builtin or actual program?

```
bruce@Bruce:~$ type -a test
test is a shell builtin
test is /usr/bin/test
bruce@Bruce:~$

bruce@Bruce:~$ file /usr/bin/test
/usr/bin/test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable
bruce@Bruce:~$
```

My system is running Ubuntu 13.04 and BASH 4.2.45(1)-release.

Comment: This comment my help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487514/in-linux-which-source-returns-nothing/17487554#comment25419789_17487554

Answer (score 9):

Seems that I doesn't really got your question on my first approach. Will try to explain it further...

Although the program `test` is part of the GNU coreutils package and will therefore being delivered with any GNU/Linux system, it is also compiled as a builtin into `bash` in most distributions. I guess that this is to improve performance as it does not need to start a child  process for every conditional statement. Needless to say that the shell will use the builtin in favour of the binary if both are present on the system. But you can call:

```
/usr/bin/test ...
```

... if you want to explicitly call the binary.

Further note that `bash` is not the only shell on most systems and other shells may don't have this builtin feature (like `dash` for example). Also there are systems which may not even have `bash` installed. For such situations there is the binary from coreutils.

---

It is likely that it is a builtin on your system. To check this type:

```
help test
```

If you see a help page it is a builtin

Also you can type:

```
type -t test
```

This shows:

```
builtin
```

on my system

Comment: Why is there a file named test on the file system then?

Comment: This is because the coreutils package contains one

Comment: Which one gets run then?

Comment: The builtin.. Note: You will find even a binary called `/bin/[` .. But there is also a builtin called `[`

Answer (score 1):

`test` is a virtual command inside bash or what you could call a `builtin`. `/usr/bin/test` exists as well as an external `command`. Along with builtins and commands there are also `functions` which you can think of more like custom builtins. The priority on how they are called are: functions first, builtins second, external binaries or commands last; but you could customize that.

If you have somehow made a function that has the same name as a builtin e.g. `cd`, to skip calling the function and call the builtin `cd` instead, you could use the builtin command `builtin` e.g. `builtin cd args`.

Likewise if you have a builtin that has same name as a command stored in the filesystem e.g. `test`, to call the command `test` instead, either you give the explicit path e.g. `/usr/bin/test` or use the builtin command `command` e.g. `command test -n xyz`.

To get more idea about it, try running these commands:

```
help
help builtin
help command
```

Answer (score 1):

Historically, `test` (and its synonym `[`) were (and remain) external programs. But most shells provide them as built-in commands for efficiency. The same is true for common commands like `true`, `false`, `printf`, `echo`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to previous answers, one can use the builtin command `enable` to enable [or disable] the builtin version of a given command `cmd` (e.g. `test`), by `enable [-n] cmd`. The documentation of `enable` takes precisely `test` as an example on my system.

`enable -a` shows the list of builtin commands and their activation state.